# Passing a JS variable to Flask API URL

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, api, flask

I made an API using Flask that has a url of this format

`localhost:5000/data/?query=<Query Goes Here>`

This API basically just returns a webapage with this small json:

```
{
"text" : "(Whatever we entered in the URL)"
}
```

I wanted to know how we can pass a Node.js variable to the URL ?

If it is not possible, how can I make an API in Python that

Takes input in JS -> Sends it to Python for Processing -> Sends output back to JS OR Displays a rendered page with that output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer you with this example.

**Takes input in JS** :

> JS file :

```
$("#test_enable").on('click', function(e) {
  $this = $(this)
  var test_id = $("#test_id_generator").val(); # get a value from test_id_generator
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            'test_id': test_id,
          },
          success: function (data) {
          location.reload(true)
        }
      });}
```

> python file:

```
def product_register_disable(request):
    test_id = request.POST.get('test_id')
```

**Sends output back to JS OR Displays a rendered page with that output**

you can show the value using `JINJA2` and python

> python side

```
@routes.route('/showtime', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def showtime():
    return render_template('showtime.html', value = 'testtest')
```

> HTML side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
<body>
    <div>{{value}}</div>
```

I hope I help.